# Proof verification using Schwarz Lemma

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, inequality

Let $f : \mathbb{D} \rightarrow \mathbb{D}$ be an holomorphic function in $\mathbb{D}$ with $f(0)=0$. Let $a_1, a_2,\ldots,a_n$ be $n$ different points in $\mathbb{D}$ with $f(a_j)=b \; \forall \;  j =1,\ldots,n$ with $b \in \mathbb{D}
\backslash \{0\}$.

We define $\varphi_{a_j}(z)=\frac{z-a_j}{1-\bar a_jz}$, $h(z)= \prod_{j=1}^{n}
\varphi_{a_j}(z)$ and $g(z) = \frac{\varphi_b (f(z))}{h(z)}$.

Prove that $|g(z)|\leq 1$, for all $z \in \mathbb{D}$.

Now I show my attemp:

First I've already prove some properties of the function $\varphi_a$ which are $\varphi_a (a) = 0$,
$\varphi_a (0) = -a$,
 $\varphi_a \; o \; \varphi_{-a} (z) = z \; \forall
a,z\in \mathbb{D}$ and that $\varphi_a$ is a biyection between  $\mathbb{D}$ and itself.

To prove that $|g(z)|\leq 1$ for all $z \in \mathbb{D}$ I do it by induction.

First I show that $|\frac{\varphi_b (f(z))}{\varphi_{a_1}(z)}|\leq 1$.

I do it by considering $\psi (w)= \varphi_b \; o \; f \; o \;\varphi_{-a}(w)$, which verifyes that $|\psi(w)| \leq 1 \; \forall w \in \mathbb{D}$ and 
$\psi (0) = 0$.

$\psi$ is also holomorphic in $\mathbb{D}$ because it is composition of holomorphic functions.

Now I can use Schwarz Lemma to conclude that $|\psi (w)| \leq |w|$. Now considering $w = \varphi_{a_1}(z)$ we get by the definition of $\psi$ that 
$|\varphi_b (f(z))| \leq |\varphi_{a_1}(z)|$, hence
$|\frac{\varphi_b (f(z))}{\varphi_{a_1}(z)}|\leq 1$.

Now I assumed that $g_{n-1}(z) := \frac{\varphi_b (f(z))}{\prod_{j=1}^{n-1}
\varphi_{a_i}(z)}$ satisfyes that $|g_{n-1}(z)| \leq 1$ for all $z \in \mathbb{D}$.

Now considering $\phi (w):= g_{n-1} \; o \; \varphi_{-a_n}(w)$, then 
$|\phi (w)| \leq 1$ in $\mathbb{D}$ and $\phi(0)=0$. Like before this function is holomorphic because it is composition of holomorphic functions.

Using Schwarz Lemma and considering $w = \varphi_{a_n}$ I get 
$|g_{n-1}(z)| \leq |\varphi_{a_n}|$, and so it is prove that 
$|g(z)|\leq 1$ in $\mathbb{D}$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Is this proof correct? Is there any step which is not clear or not correct?
Someone sees another way easier or not to make the proof?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your proof looks correct to me. The steps are pretty clear and you used Schwarz's Lemma nicely. I don't an easier way to do this right now, but I'll give it some thought

Comment: Thanks for looking at it, I just wanted to know if some step was not correct or maybe something must be checked

Comment: Also, I suggest looking more thoroughly at those $\varphi_a (z)$ that show up in your exercise. You can characterize the analytic bijections from the open unit disk to itself using them very nicely, so it's an interesting (and useful) piece of knowledge. I recommend looking at Conway's book, pages 130-132.

Comment: @Nowras yes I studied then in class and are very useful in this type of excercise. Thank you I will look the Conway